# How to set cross-Origin in SetBackgroundImage of fabric js

Tags: cross-domain, fabricjs

I am trying to fetch an image from amazon s3 bucket.
I have configured my bucket with CORs header.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
 <CORSRule>
   <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
   <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
   <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
   <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
   <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
   <MaxAgeSeconds>2592000</MaxAgeSeconds>
   <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
 </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

My canvas background image is setting like This :

```
canvas.setBackgroundImage(ImageURL, function () {canvas.renderAll();},
{
   top: top,
   left: left,
   scaleX: scaleFactor,
   scaleY: scaleFactor,
   crossOrigin: 'anonymous'
});
```

It works in chrome and Mozilla in windows but not work in Safari on Mac.

I don't understand,  where I am wrong.
Please correct me.

Comment: I have the same issue, I'm using fabricJS 1.7.22. I'm getting same error while loading image from s3.

Comment: Which version of fabric are you using ?

Comment: I am using fabric js  version 1.7.22,

Comment: I have got solution, it's working now,
Solution : I was sending two request for same image , one for get image height and width and second request for load image into canvas, in first request it was not set cross origin, and second request is send from caching which is without cross origin, and it was throw an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

I already added a comment but still, this issue looks like this.
and a solution is to set cross-origin in the first request also.